How can we subtract elements of the unit group so that the difference is still in the unit group
I am trying to find the rank of a matrix formed by the characters of a finite ring over the rationals. The order of the matrix is the number of elements in the unit group by the number of elements in the dual group. Any help will be greatly appreciated
